# how to set billing agreement "false" in programmatically in magento?

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.9

How can I stop Billing Agreement generation in Magento in programetically?
I already set billing agreement "auto" but its generate all customer order with all products but want to set recurring products only.

Please suggest for it enable billing agreement only for selected products buy.